# How to set multi AlarmManager with different time

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

**Hi everyone, I am trying to set multi AlarmManager with different time , and using this code**

```
public void StartAppNotifications( String title ,int h ,int m ) {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, m);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


        if (!calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlertReceiver.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", title);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

        }

    }
```

**it works once, if this method is called one time, but if called more than once it is not working 
I am trying to call it like this**

```
StartAppNotifications("alarm text" ,18 ,30);
```

Comment: What arguments do you pass StartAppNotifications() the second time you call it ?

Comment: if you aske about second it is not importan , i just want to use  StartAppNotifications("alarm text" ,18 ,30); for 4 time like StartAppNotifications("text1" ,18 ,30); 
StartAppNotifications("text2" ,18 ,35); 
StartAppNotifications("text3" ,18 ,40); 
StartAppNotifications("text4" ,18 ,45);

Comment: Can you use a different pending Intent every time you call the function,e .g. count up the requestCode from `100`, `101`, `102`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#set) about AlarmManager, when you set a second alarm that uses the same pending intent, it replaces the original alarm

Therefore, you need to use a different PendingIntent for each of your repeating alarms, for example using flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT` to create your PendingIntent

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```